# What is the benefit of using % notation?

Tags: ruby

I see literal notation like `%w[foo bar]` being used all the time, but I dont see the benefit in using that over `["foo", "bar"]`. Is it used as convention, or is this some performance/time benefit?

Comment: It's purely a sugar. Some people find it more readable, some do not.

Comment: `%w` also lines up with other handy quoting notations (`%r`, `%x`, `%q`, `%Q`, `%W`); `%r` is a simple way to avoid backslash madness in a regex with with a lot of slashes, `%q` and `%Q` are nice when you have a string with a lot of embedded quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some cases it's more readable. Compare these made-up examples:

```
%w(the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog)
["the", "quick", "brown", "fox", "jumped", "over", "the", "lazy", "dog"]
"the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog".split(' ')
```

While the third one is *almost* as readable as the first one, it performs worse (needs to allocate and populate array). The first two, on the other hand, are processed at parse time.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no any performance benefit. Sometimes it's easier and looks better if you use this. Easier to write and more simple `%(One Two Three Four)` is, that's all...